# Error invoking back-end POST web service from IBM Mobilefirst http adapter

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am trying to invoke a back-end POST webservice from an http adapter created for IBM Mobilefirst. 
Here is the code:

```
var input = {
    method : 'post',
    returnedContentType : 'json',
    path : '/JLRDurbanPilot/locator',
body:{
    contentType:"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    content: JSON.stringify([{"model":"L"}])
    }
}
return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
```

When i run this, i get an HTTP status 400 error with the description - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

The 400 error comes from your back-end server.

I recommend observing the request through a tool such as Wireshark, and seeing if it corresponds to what your back-end expects.
You can also look at your backend logs and try to debug what the server receives and what it tries to do with this request.

One possibility I see, try:

```
JSON.stringify({"model":"L"})
```

Instead of

```
JSON.stringify([{"model":"L"}])
```

Meaning, are you sure you meant to send an array?

Comment: I would go a step further, send a request in using a tool such as a POSTMAN, once you know exactly what payload is accepted then you can  replication that in your JSON Stringify and compare what's being sent using WireShark. Note that MobileFirst studio includes a TCP/IP monitor so you can use that instead of WireShark